# Proper way to crop image in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I try to crop image with this way

```
var crop = new Kinetic.Image({ 
    image: img , 
    x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, heigth: 100, 
    crop : {
        x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, heigth: 100
    }
});
```

and it doesn't work see in http://jsfiddle.net/cm5jj/

and then I try to fill rect with image

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({  
    x: 100,  
    y: 100,  
    width: 100,  
    height: 100,  
    fill:{  
        image: img,  
        crop:{  
            x: 0,  
            y: 0,  
            width: 100,  
            height: 100  
        },   
    }
});
```

and still doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/cm5jj/1/
please help. 
thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you're cropping the image to the exact dimensions of the image size, which means that you aren't cropping at all.  try setting width and height to values greater than the crop width and height values.

Also, if you're wanting to animate the sprite, you should be using Kinetic.Sprite() instead

Comment: I want to change image when mouseover/mouseout/mousedown and click.
so I think draw image with crop should be more suitable

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, you mistyped `height` with `heigth`. Maybe spell check will help with this.

As to your second code snippet, to fill a rect with an image, you need `fillPatternImage` property, which requires an image object, and `fill` is used to fill with color.

#### `fill` example:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({  
    x: 100,  
    y: 100,  
    width: 100,  
    height: 100,  
    fill: 'blue'
});
```

#### `fillPatternImage` example:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({  
        x: 100,  
        y: 100,  
        width: 100,  
        height: 100,  
        fillPatternImage: img
    });
    // Add rect to your layer, and do drawing
};
img.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg';
```